# Connect to OpenShift MySQL with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, openshift, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to access MySQL from OpenShift using MySQL Workbench. To do this I connected through SSH with Putty and created a SSH tunnel: `L3316 -> localhost:3306`.

When I setup the connection from MySQL Workbench to `localhost:3316` and test the connection I get

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet, system error: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was how I set up the tunnel. It should have been `L3316 -> x.x.x.x:3306`, where `x.x.x.x` is the MySQL host. You can see this by running `rhc-list-ports` in the OpenShift SSH console and you'll get something like

```
mysql -> x.x.x.x:3306
```

It might worth to also check if the user has access to the database and can connect from a remote host, but then you will get

> Access denied for user 'blahblah'@'a.b.c.d' (using password: YES)